# How to make a grid properly and render it faster?

Tags: modeling, rendering, wireframe

Should I use grid fill tool and then use wireframe modifier, or subdivide the mesh? I want to make a grid and then use wireframe modifier.

Answer (score 3):

Make a plane, and add the subsurf modifier. Change the subdivision algorithm from Catmull-Clark to Simple. Now add a wireframe modifier. You can increase or decrease the density of your wireframe grid by changing the number of subdivisions in the subsurf modifier.